# Issues With Combined Audio/Video Capture with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ffmpeg-filters

I am making an application where I am using FFMPEG to output a specific window on my computer. The video side works really well but starts struggling severely when I add audio into the mix (no pun intended, lol). With just video, I get the usual 30 fps. When I add dshow audio into the same command as the video, the fps drops to 5 with a ton of duplicated and dropped frames. I tried doing two streams (one with video and one with audio). That works great except the audio stream is like 20 to 30 seconds behind the video.

Is there any suggestions that could fix either the glitchy video when using the dshow audio in the same stream or the delay of the separate audio stream? Any help is appreciated!